# Using perl script to fill up hard drive - can this be done more efficiently?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have written a Perl script (Strawberry) to fill up some old hard drives with some semi-random numbers a couple of times before sending them to recycling.
The script creates a ~ 100mb file with random 0's and 1's which is then written 10 times into a file.
This process is then repeated depending on hard disk size (in the example only 3 times for testing purposes).

Currently, its taking around 36 seconds per file.
My question is: what changes can I make to the script to speed this up?

Here is the script in full:

```
my $master = "c:/programme/tools/filluphd/master.txt";
my $rd;

my $log = "c:/programme/tools/filluphd/log.log";

my $file = "f:/file_";

#create master
open (MASTER, ">", $master);

for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++)
{
    $rd = int(rand(2)); 
    print MASTER $rd;
}

close (MASTER);

open (LOG, ">", $log);
print LOG "start: ".localtime()."\n";
my $start_time = time();
my $random;
open (MASTER, "<", $master) or die "cannot open master: $!"."\n";
while (<MASTER>)
{
    $random .= $_;
}
close (MASTER);
for ($n = 0; $n <= 2 ; $n++) 
{
    my $file_start = time();
    my $filename = $file.$n.".txt";
    my $i = 0;
    open (FILE, ">", $filename);
    for ($i; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        print FILE $random;
    }
    close (FILE);
    my $file_end = time();
    my $file_runtime = $file_end - $file_start;
    print LOG "file ".$filename." took ".$file_runtime." seconds!"."\n";
}

my $end_time = time();
my $run_time = $end_time - $start_time;
print LOG "run time: ".$run_time." seconds"."\n";
print LOG "finish: ".localtime()."\n";
close (LOG);
```

Comment: I would go here: https://partedmagic.com/

Comment: Yeah, not really what I want. I know there are professional solutions, but why not roll my own because I can?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `Format` command from Windows? It can overwrite the entire disk with random data as often as you like. I've never known these things to be fast.

Comment: 1) I challenge your claim that this fills up your hard drive, especially on flash drives. How about coming with a working solution first? And by this I mean use a tool created by someone who knows what they are doing. Security is something best left to security professionals.

Comment: 2) In terms of bits, you are using 15 zeroes for every 1. In terms of bytes, you are using only 2 of the 256 possible values. What's the point of that???

Comment: 3) You only attempt one pass, but scrubbers usually do multiple passes (write to the same location multiple times). But that might not be necessary; it depends on your threat model. But one pass is not enough to completely erase the magnetic fields that make up the data.

Comment: 4) You don't check for errors. Your program might fail to (over)write anything at all, and you would never know.

Comment: @ikegami re 1) Yes, this filled up my hard drive until it was out of space.Yes, I know that there are professional tools. No, I am not claiming this is as good as a professional solution.
re 2) true, I had not thought of that, thank you for the hint.
re 3) yes, this only has one pass on purpose, I am aware that you need several passes.
re 4) yes, this is also correct. Thing is, perl print to file does not fail if the drive is filled up, it will just write as much space there is and then create 0 length files from then on.

Comment: @Snorik - you could use [DBAN](https://dban.org/) to erase disks. If you are in Linux then you could use something like `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/{your_disk} bs=1M` a few times on HDD to fill it with random data (not fully secure, does not comply with erasure standards). Some day I read an article when a HDD was retrieved from sunk ship which was in salted water for about 6 month -- disk was cleaned up and all data was recovered by data recovery company.

Comment: @Snorik - [HDD Wipe/Erase standards](https://www.blancco.com/blog-comprehensive-list-data-wiping-erasure-standards/)

Comment: @Snorik -- [CBL Data Shredder](https://www.lifewire.com/cbl-data-shredder-review-2619129), [DoD 5220.22-M Data Wipe Method](https://www.lifewire.com/dod-5220-22-m-2625856)

Comment: @PolarBear that is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Re "*1) Yes, this filled up my hard drive until it was out of space*", Maybe, but that doesn't you filled up the hard drive with 1s and 0s, and it definitely doesn't mean everything was overwritten. My comment stands. Your tool doesn't even come close to wiping your drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some measuring and found out that the Case the HD is in is USB2-only.
That means with about 30MB/s it is completely saturated and the windows tools show this.
Speedwise, there is not much else to do.